# Is this the right way of doing and displaying validation on WPF, Prism, MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, prism-6

I'm new to WPF, Prism, and MVVM and I'm finding very little information out there. When it comes to validation and displaying validation errors, I read quite a few blog posts and articles and none seemed to work anymore.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

The ViewModel (minus other fields for simplification) seems to have a lot of boilerplate, maybe I'm missing something? Am I reinventing the wheel the way I'm storing and handling errors:

```
namespace Configurator.ViewModels {
    public class RegistrationViewModel : BindableBase, INotifyDataErrorInfo {
        private string _email;
        public string Email {
            get { return _email; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _email, value); }
        }

        public DelegateCommand RegisterCommand { get; private set; }

        public RegistrationViewModel() {
            RegisterCommand = new DelegateCommand(Register);
            ClearAllErrors();
        }

        private void Register() {
            ClearAllErrors();
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email)) {
                SetError("Email", "We need your email address to register you.");
            }
        }

        private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> _errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Errors {
            get { return _errors; }
        }

        public void SetError(string propertyName, string errorMessage) {
            if (!_errors.ContainsKey(propertyName)) {
                _errors.Add(propertyName, new List<string>());
            }
            _errors[propertyName].Add(errorMessage);

            RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }

        protected void ClearError(string propertyName) {
            if (_errors.ContainsKey(propertyName)) {
                _errors.Remove(propertyName);
            }

            RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }

        protected void ClearAllErrors() {
            var errors = _errors.Select(error => error.Key).ToList();

            foreach (var propertyName in errors)
                ClearError(propertyName);
        }

        public void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName) {
            ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            RaisePropertyChanged("Errors");
        }

        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged = delegate { return; };

        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName) {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || !_errors.ContainsKey(propertyName)) {
                return null;
            }
            return _errors[propertyName];
        }

        public bool HasErrors {
            get { return _errors.Any(x => x.Value != null && x.Value.Count > 0); }
        }
    }
}
```

When it comes to the view, I had to add this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:ErrorFormatter x:Key="ErrorFormatter" />
    <local:ErrorPresent x:Key="ErrorPresent" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Will every view require it? Then the field itself looks like this:

```
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Content="Email:" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="6"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" x:Name="email" Margin="6" Text="{Binding Email}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"  Margin="6,0,6,6" Foreground="Red" 
               Text="{Binding Errors, Converter={StaticResource ErrorFormatter}, ConverterParameter=Email}"
               Visibility="{Binding Errors, Converter={StaticResource ErrorPresent}, ConverterParameter=Email}"/>
```

Is binding to `Errors` the right thing? I've seen examples in which it was binding to `Errors[Email]` but that would raise an exception when that key doesn't exist.

This mean that I had to create two `IValueConverter`s:

```
public sealed class ErrorFormatter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var allErrors = (Dictionary<string, List<string>>)value;
        var fieldName = (string)parameter;
        if (allErrors.ContainsKey(fieldName) && allErrors[fieldName].Count > 0) {
            foreach (string error in allErrors[fieldName]) {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
            }
            return String.Join("\n", allErrors[fieldName]).Trim();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and

```
class ErrorPresent : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var allErrors = (Dictionary<string, List<string>>)value;
        var fieldName = (string)parameter;
        if (allErrors.ContainsKey(fieldName) && allErrors[fieldName].Count > 0) {
            return "Visible";
        } else {
            return "Collapsed";
        };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It feels like anybody who needs to display validation errors would have to write these as well, so, am I missing something? I've noticed some expressions using `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` but I couldn't get them to work the way I'm storing errors?

What feels like a smell is that the fields are marked with the red border automatically which I believe it's due to `INotifyDataErrorInfo` but then I couldn't find any further automatic behavior to wire properly. Am I missing something big?